# Was this teacher fair towards me?

Tags: teaching

So last week, I had to get a COVID test due to me being ill. However my teacher decided that because I wasn’t there, that I would get a zero on the assignment that was posted and I wouldn’t have a chance to catch up so I could finish the work that was assigned? It was band class so I couldn’t have worked from home. Is this fair for my teacher to do this?

Comment: Was this a university course?

Comment: If this is a high-school class then the question is off topic. But you should, in that case, take the issue to the principal and have your parents make a big issue of it.

Comment: The most productive question to ask is probably not whether the teacher was fair, but whether the teacher was acting within the policies of the institution and within public law.

Comment: "Fair" is a matter of opinion...and the opinions of random people on the internet will count for very little. What is your goal here?

Comment: Did you explain beforehand to the teacher the situation? I think a sending a note in advance to him or would have been the proper thing to do, and maybe you did so.